# Is there an equivalent to Trac written in PHP?

Tags: php, svn, bug-tracking, trac

Is there an equivalent to [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) written in PHP? I need something that integrates with SVN and is free. It should allow me to browse the SVN source, have some kind of bug tracking and show recent changes in the SVN. A wiki isn't essential.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, you need an all-in-one wiki + bugtracker + workflow + svn repos viwer written in php?

Comment: SVN source viewer, bug tracker and recent changes in SVN. Wiki isn't essential.

Comment: I personally use Trac because I haven't been able to find another packaged solution that's just as flexible. However, if you don't mind using multiple packages (and you said you don't need a wiki) then I'd suggest: - [MantisBT](http://www.mantisbt.org/) - a free popular web-based bugtracking system - [ViewSVN](http://viewsvn.berlios.de/) - web interface for viewing SVN repositories

Comment: If a tool suits your needs, why the language in which it is implemented matters so much? A good example might be Ruby on Rails project, which used Trac as a bug tracker and repository browser for quite a long time. Trac has it's issues, but it is extremely easy to setup, even if you have no Python experience.

Comment: you can try out also http://svnmanager.sourceforge.net/ for the svn stuff , as for the trac equivalent I would suggest mantiz, very light and gets the job done. I use the combination of mantiz and dotproject.

Comment: Powerful bugtracking with SVN browse: [The Bug Genie](http://www.thebuggenie.com/)

Comment: There is a new project from Wez (PDO fame) here: http://netevil.org/blog/2010/01/mtrack-a-software-development-tracker-wiki

Comment: I'd like to recommend redmine http://www.redmine.org/

Comment: My personal recommendation is "CandyCane" which is port of Redmine into CakePHP.
Development is stil active. This project using PHP5.3, 5.4 and 5.5 with 40 of contributors from the world wide. https://github.com/yandod/candycane
http://yandod.github.io/candycane/ You can develop plugin for CandyCane with PHP syntax.
This can be match with many unique situation.

Comment: FYI: https://traq.io/ was intended as a full clone of Trac, but it ended up going a different route