# PHP alternative to trac?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an equivalent to Trac written in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349241/is-there-an-equivalent-to-trac-written-in-php)

Are there any PHP alternatives to Edgewall's Trac solution which works on Python, and not really portable?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure what ct2k7 means by not really portable.  I sympathize with the difficulty of finding a Python hosting provider.  Try WebFaction.

Comment: @Sean... I'd be using it on a dedicated server, my own. @Bill, by portable, as in, you don't have to install it or have a daemon to run it, i.e interdependent.

Comment: Re "my crappy host" comment. It is quite common to be in a situation where you are asked to develop something but have very little control over the devlopemnt environment or architecture. Your project sponser my have choosen a sub-optimal hosting company but can you as a "solution provider" really recommend a disruptive mogration of the whole host environment as part of your solution.  For a professional developer to suggest such a change just to install some bug tracking software is unprofessional.

Comment: FYI: https://traq.io/ was intended as PHP clone, but ended up going its own route.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't really a single project that duplicates all features of Trac.

Here are a couple of PHP applications you could look at to see if they do what you need:

- http://www.dotproject.net/
- http://www.mantisbt.org/

Comment: why is every "solution" on this page so UGLY .... like seriously ... bug tracking should be clean, and simple.  Really wish there was something more modern built in Bootstrap3/HTML5/jQuery, and supported SVN browsing ....  Trac is ok... but it's in PYTHON....  really not that portable.

Answer (score 9):

I'd try [The Bug Genie](http://www.thebuggenie.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Think this reply is too late, but have come across forks of old sourceforge which are pretty feature rich and stable. But have their own idiosyncrasies in installation or running. But these are very good tools to have a look at.

[Gforge](http://gforge.org)
has a commercial angle to it and is one of the oldest.

[Fusionforge](http://fusionforge.org)
recently forked out of Gforge

[Codendi](http://codendi.org) is developed by Xerox and is now open source. Think its one of the most feature rich ones (with some quirks in installation and certain design decisions)

PS: oops cant post more than 1 link as im new. One can just add .org tld to the names of other two tools.

**EDIT**: I missed one - [Chaw](http://thechaw.com). Its built on Cakephp and is fairly good. I have been procrastinating on some fixes to make it work in shared hosting.

Comment: don't worry, I'm always open :)

Answer (score 1):

Try:
http://www.jotbug.org/jotbug/wiki/OverView

Comment: The jotbug.org domain appears to be dead.

Answer (score 1):

[InDefero](http://www.indefero.net/) is a Google Code clone in PHP.

It's not as mature as Trac or Redmine but there seems to be active development and a lot of functionalities already implemented and working.

Comment: It is true they seem to be offering plans for a hosted version but it is open source software GPU/GPL (http://www.indefero.net/open-source/) and therefore can be hosted by you wherever you want and modified as you see fit as long as you follow the license.

Answer (score 1):

To complete what Deepak Sathya said about Codendi, I would add that Codendi includes a vry customized and powerful tracker system but also a lot of other tools useful for development and project : docman, wiki, Hudson interface, graph, gantt chart... See Codendi features : http://www.codendi.com/features.php

Comment: Please disclose your affiliation when recommending your own products/projects.